# What is the redo shortcut in Octave?

Tags: octave

What is the shortcut for "redo" in Octave? I tried `Cntrl + Y` but that didn't work, and I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

Octave uses Emacs key bindings by default. In Emacs you would first do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, after which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) would undo.

When using Emacs bindings in Matlab, redo is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the official GUI, there's a "Shortcuts" tab under the "Preferences" menu. The default seems to be Ctrl-Y but it may be set to something else on your system for whatever reason (or not set at all). Note that, in that "Shortcuts" tab, the 'Undo' shortcut appears under "edit menu", whereas the "Redo" shortcut appears under the "Editor" category further down.